# Joomla module to display list of articles with specific tags

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

I have a question about Joomla 3.1 Tagging feature. It works well and when I go to create a module from the admin it gives me the following 2 options for Tags - http://awesomescreenshot.com/0dc1gnx101

Module of Similar tags, and Module to display most popular tags (tags used most). What I need is simply a module to display a list of articles from specific tags I enter, much like the module for categories.

Is there a way to do this or custom html/php I can write in a custom html module to display this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to make a module like that but there is also one available here

https://github.com/lasinducharith/joomla-tags-selected

That's a summer of code student and I'm sure he'd be delighted to get some feed back if you try it.